# Understanding integer overflow with `int` and `long long` variables

Tags: c, integer-overflow

Why do these programs produce different outputs?

### [Program 1](http://ideone.com/Q3Nhhu):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    long long bigger = 0;
    int smaller = INT_MAX;

    bigger = smaller * 2;
    printf("Smaller = %d\n", smaller);
    printf("Bigger = smaller * 2 = %lld\n\n", bigger);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

> Smaller = 2147483647
>
> Bigger = smaller * 2 = -2

---

### [Program 2](http://ideone.com/fkddEj):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main()
{
    long long bigger = 0;
    int smaller = INT_MAX;

    bigger = smaller;
    bigger *= 2;
    printf("Smaller = %d\n", smaller);
    printf("Bigger = smaller * 2 = %lld\n\n", bigger);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

> Smaller = 2147483647
>
> Bigger = smaller * 2 = 4294967294

---

My guess is that program 1 attempts to store the multiplication result in a temporary storage which is of the same size as `int`. So it overflows. Whereas, program 2, stores the multiplication result in the larger storage.

Am I correct?

Additionally, if I have made any grievous mistake in either of the programs, please let me know (because according to me, those programs compile perfectly)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`smaller` is an `int`, so is the literal `2`. So their product is an `int` too. Since `INT_MAX * 2` can't be represented by an `int` (by definition, pretty much), it overflows leading to undefined behavior.

If, however, you store the value in a `long long`, then, when performing the multiplication, default integer promotion (the "usual arithmetic conversion") happens. Now, if your `long long` can represent `INT_MAX * 2`, you will end up with something semantically equivalent with `bigger = bigger * (long long)2`, which works as expected.

Comment: An addendum for those that don't understand the "if your `long long` can represent `INT_MAX * 2`" bit: `INT_MAX == LLONG_MAX` may be true, in which case the result will overflow.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune, Interesting. Do you know any specific cases where `INT_MAX == LLONG_MAX` is true?

Comment: @AnishRam I do not know of such an implementation, but it doesn't hurt to remain portable when possible. I can't imagine an embedded system would make `int` 64-bit, but a similar system that is more realistic might actually have `CHAR_BIT = 32`, in which case it might be the same as a `short` and `int` and possibly even `long`. It is all theoretical, but if you can dream it, you can build it.